# JDBC error while loading context for Junit/Spring test

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to setup basic testing environment using Junit with Spring Data using xml config.

When trying to run the the ExampleTest, while the context is loading, this happens:

http://pastebin.com/hiZKv8hV

With the most relevant error probably being:

```
289  testservice-server-model  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Connected to     PostgreSQL version 9.9 using JDBC driver PostgreSQL Native Driver version PostgreSQL 9.1 JDBC4 (build 901).
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Which made me think my url/credentials for db are incorrect, however I have quadruple checked dataSource url/credentials to make sure they are not the problem.

The files are:

ExampleTest.java

```
package co.testEnv.server.services.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import co.testEnv.server.model.repositories.UserRepository;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:testContext.xml" })
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFind() throws Exception {

    }

}
```

testContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="co.testEnv.server.model" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="co.testEnv.server.model.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testEnv_test" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

UserRepository.java

```
package co.testEnv.server.model.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import co.testEnv.server.model.entities.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

All hints will be appriciated.

Comment: I see that there is a NullPointerException in your output, can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @VladimirTikhomirov you got it in the pastebin url.